# APK tool returning the content of the res folder in encrypted language

Tags: android, exception, decompiling, apktool

I have used the APKTool to decompile the apk file.

For that, first I rename the apk file to zip and then extract it to get the res folder.

Now problem is I got the res folder with its respective subfolders, but when I opened any XML file in that, I got the text in some different language (as shown below).

[image]

After that I have tried it using command line, but when I run the command `apktool d sample.apk` I got the following error:

```
D:\Softwares\apktool_2.0.0rc4>apktool d sample.apk
I: Baksmaling...
I: Loading resource table...
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Could not decode ars
c file
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:56)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibRes
ources.java:491)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.jav
a:74)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.jav
a:66)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.getResTable(Androlib.java:50)
        at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.getResTable(ApkDecoder.java:189)
        at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:114)
        at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:146)
        at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Expected: 0x001c0001, got: 0x00000000
        at brut.util.ExtDataInput.skipCheckInt(ExtDataInput.java:48)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.StringBlock.read(StringBlock.java:44)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:10
2)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:83)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:49)
        ... 8 more
```

What can I try next to solve this?

Comment: `first i rename the apk file to zip` ... **don't do that**.

Comment: @DerGolem yes,i got your point,but what i want to say is by converting zip to apk is my first approach. and in second approach, i got the error related to `brut.androlib.AndrolibException`

Comment: Because an apk **is** a zip, but it contains **compiled resources**. Is then ApkTool's job to decompile them. The decompiled source code will be in **smali**.

Comment: Is this APK from a specific OEM? Errors like shown above expose a difference in the expected byte format vs what apktool knows. This only occurs with highly modified OEM apks such as Huawei, MIUI, etc.

Comment: Did you solve you problem?